# jquery rightclick contextmenu on applet

Tags: jquery, applet, contextmenu

I am trying to create a right-click jquery contextmenu on an applet object.
Able to get the rightclick options on any other elements like div or span but not able to get it done on applet object.

First of all, Can we do this on an applet object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If its a java applet or flash applet then it cannot be done through javascript unless there is some "bridge" built into the applet code. if your applet is not that complex it might be worth the investment of time it takes to rewrite it in plain old jS

Comment: Thanks for the reply Frank. Even I have the same idea which is actually the best option but the applet I am using is a third party library and I don't have its source code. my bad...